# Normalizing brightness/contrast on a mobile device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, camera, photo

I am working on a document scanner application and want to have (almost) consistent looking scanned documents no matter if the scan was taken in light or dark environments. (see images below)
Apples Native Scanner from the Notes App somehow achieves this and I wonder how: is it histogram magic? is it measuring brightness/contrast and then adding/lowering it to some predefined level? is there even a iOS standard filter achieving just that?

i didnt even know what to google for

[image: light environment]
[image: light environment result]

[image: dark environment]
[image: dark environment result]

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption/logic on how Notes Scanner app achieves that consistency with brightness/contrast *might* be correct, and it makes sense.

Since you are working on a Document Scanning app for iOS devices, I would suggest working with `VisionKit` by Apple:

> Use the iOS camera to scan documents like those you capture in the Notes app.
> VisionKit is a small framework that lets your app use the system's document scanner. Available for **iOS 13.0+** [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionkit)

It allows natively scan documents. That means you will achieve the exact same result in terms of consistency and quality of scanned images.

Comment: Unfortunately that means you have to use the whole Apple Scanner which you can’t customize in any way